# How to upload a .txt file to SQL table every 5 miniutes?

Tags: sql, file-io, mariadb, loaddata

I'm trying to upload a .txt file to a table in my db every 5 minutes. When using this code I get an error saying Load Data infile is not aloud in a stored procedure. What are my alternatives?  I'm not to familiar with anything outside SQL, python and java so a local solution in SQL would be preferred. Thanks!

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE student_update ()
 BEGIN
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'text file path'
    INTO TABLE StudentTest
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
END


CREATE EVENT update
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO
    EXEC student_update
```

Comment: `OPENROWSET(BULK...)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Is that Mariadb (`load data infile`)? Or SQL Server (`exec`)?

Comment: `OPENROWSET` is not a MariaDB function.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Will it overwrite parts of the table?  Do you need to replace the entire table?  Did you ask this question before?